# How can I re-partition after Installation (dual boot)?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I recently received a new PC that came with an SSD and HDD, and I installed a second HDD. I then installed ubuntu alongside Windows using [this](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html) tutorial.

However, I didn't do anything special for partitioning during the installation and now am left with the situation where everything is on the SSD.  I have two questions:

1. What is a reasonable strategy for partitioning the drives and what should be mounted on them?
2. How can I migrate the existing folders to the new partitions?

I've looked up a few strategies, but I am not sure which partitions I should move to the new HDDs and what the sizings should be.  I would like to keep the OSes on the SSD to speed up boot times.  I think everything else can go on the HDDs.

Also, I noticed that the ubuntu installation seemed to break one of the HDDs into 3 partitions and put ubuntu--vg-swap_1 and ubuntu--vg-root on one of them.  Not a big deal, but now I cannot repartition that drive easily.

Since I just completed the installations, I really have nothing invested yet in this machine and if it is easier to start over, I can do so.

```
$ lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb                     8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdb2                  8:18   0   488M  0 part 
├─sdb3                  8:19   0   1.8T  0 part 
│ ├─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:1    0  31.9G  0 lvm  
│ └─ubuntu--vg-root   253:0    0   1.8T  0 lvm  
└─sdb1                  8:17   0   512M  0 part 
sr0                    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sda                     8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sda1                  8:1    0   1.8T  0 part 
nvme0n1               259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p5           259:5    0  96.1G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p3           259:3    0 347.9G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p1           259:1    0   500M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p6           259:6    0  31.9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p4           259:4    0   468M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p2           259:2    0   128M  0 part
```

I am using this machine to run VMs and for software development.  I also have no need to view files from both Windows and Ubuntu, so ext4 is a perfectly fine format.

**EDIT:** Added screenshots from gparted.
[image: nvme]
[image: sda]
[image: sdb]

Some more info as per request:

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        1.4G         28G        493M        1.4G         28G
Swap:           31G          0B         31G
$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/nvme0n1p6                          partition   33443836    0   -1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking, when you have an SSD and a HDD, Windows and Ubuntu go on the SSD, and /home and swap go on the HDD. If you wish to share files between Windows and Ubuntu, EXT4 is not the best choice, as Windows can't read/write to EXT4 without a special driver (and those tend to corrupt Ubuntu), so use NTFS for the common area. It looks almost like you've installed Ubuntu twice... once "along side" of Windows, and another using LVM disk format. Does that sound correct? It would be very helpful to see screenshots of `gparted` view of nvme0n1, sda, and sdb.

Comment: @heynnema I added the screenshots.  I did not install ubuntu twice;  I did put the installtion USB back in to see if I could repartition properly, but abandoned that after I saw that "do something else" was probably going to install a second version.  I reverted those changes and nothing was installed.

Comment: If sda is going to be your common area, as I mentioned, you should use NTFS. sdb sure looks like it (began to) install a 2nd Ubuntu as LVM disks. You can see / (root) is mounted on nvme0n5 and on LVM volume ubuntu--vg-root (sdb3).  What was your intent for sdb? Show me `free -h` and `swapon -s` and `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: @heynnema Added more info.  As I mentioned in the post, I don't have any need to share between Windows and Ubuntu, so ext4 is fine.  I may end up creating a small partition for transferring files, or a partition for Windows data files, but I haven't decided that yet.

Comment: @heynnema Leaving for the weekend, but I will be back on Tuesday.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: Ah, I see... "**no** need to view files from both Windows and Ubuntu"... I overlooked the "no". What were your plans for sdb?

Comment: LVM is an advanced partitioning scheme. It is more complex but some users like it. You cannot use standard partition tools for the logical volumes/partitions inside the physical partitions. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if the partitions can migrated/ but if you go for a fresh install folloing  a simple/general approach to squeeze performance for VM usage:

**on SSD:**

- ***/boot*** - This should exist on ssd to improve Boot Time (Q: are you planning to restart the machine once its up and running often, if not this belongs in the HDD)
- ***/swap*** - This is paging memory being treated as RAM which, super essentail to have this here for VM runtime performance, multitasking, large applications
  (use the rest of the SSD space for rest of the OS files)

**HDD:**

All VM users that get created can have their /home dir mounted from the HDD